# How to create a Mac droplet to process text input

Tags: macos, droplet

We need a macOS application which acts as a droplet for text. Any text that I drop onto the application icon should be processed. With script editor and automator I can only create droplets for files and folders, but that's not what I have to drop.

Comment: I don’t believe you can drag and drop text onto Automator apps. The nearest you can get is to choose `New`->`Service` then `Run Applescript` then add code like `on run {input}`

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in [question 501079](/a/506955/4689919)